# How to write EF in linq to include comparison by lower case

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have this query: `select lower(Name) from User`

How to make the same with linq to EF avoiding to user linq to object.

Comment: Is it necessary to have execute the code on the DB or would it be ok to make the to lower part in LINQish but execute it on the application?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
var query = context.Users.Select(u => u.Name.ToLower());
```

Entity Framework can translate String.ToLower into SQL. This query will be translated as:

```
SELECT 
LOWER([Extent1].[Name]) AS [C1]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
```