# Project Server integration & Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint

I'm trying to do some integration with Project Server. I encountered a error which i didn't got while using normal Linq query

```
projContext.Load(projContext.Projects,
                    c => c.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(pr => pr.Name, pr => pr.FinishDate, pr => pr.Tasks).Where(pr => (pr.Name).ToLower() == (ProjectName).ToLower()));
```

The error message is

```
The 'ToLower' member cannot be used in the expression.
```

Can anyone let me know why, I even tried string.compare that also didn't work.

Comment: Please refer to this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885885/how-to-write-ef-in-linq-to-include-comparison-by-lower-case

Answer (score 0):

Your linq queries behind the curtains are translated to t-sql statement. Microsoft didn't implement ToLower function convertion. The same is true about compare. If you want to use ToLower in order to avoid case-sensitivity then I can tell you that by default ms sql is case-insensitive. So if you didn't change it by intention, probably you don't need ToLower function