# Lambda Filtering using StartsWith is not working in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

I am using Lambda expression for searching. I am searching on 3 fields i.e. name, address, email. I have written the following lambda expression in the view of a controller:

```
return View(db.SalesPersons.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(search.ToUpper()) || x.Address.StartsWith(search.ToUpper()) || x.Email.StartsWith(search.ToUpper())).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
```

But when I am debugging the application, it is generating following sql:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[IID] AS [IID], 
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address], 
    [Extent1].[City] AS [City], 
    [Extent1].[Pin] AS [Pin], 
    [Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
    [Extent1].[Password] AS [Password], 
    [Extent1].[ContactNo1] AS [ContactNo1], 
    [Extent1].[ContactNo2] AS [ContactNo2], 
    [Extent1].[Email] AS [Email]
    FROM [dbo].[SalesPerson] AS [Extent1]
```

Clearly the where cause is missing. So it is returning all the records without filtering. I am not sure what is the problem. Any clue?

Thanks

Partha

Comment: `it is generating following sql`: how have you tested this?

Comment: You can get the sql during debugging.

Comment: What is the value of `search`?

Comment: It is a value from textbox. The value is OK.

Comment: Just checking... because it might be an optimization thing if it's empty.

Comment: The thing is; I use this kind of queries sometimes, and they all work, so in general `Lambda Filtering using StartsWith is not working in c#` is very unlikely.

Comment: I am also not sure if the `search.ToUpper()` is correctly translated to SQL, if not you should get an exception at runtime saying the query cannot be translated.

Comment: But why it is retrieving all the records. In that case the list must be null..

Comment: The combination of StartsWith and ToUpper is looking smelly to me. Can you try to try storing the uppercase string in a new c# variable and passing that to StartsWith?

Comment: All non-null strings start with `string.Empty`.: see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ON22le

Comment: Can you also add your `DbContext` code?

Comment: Can you share your database records and other code flows implicitly?

Comment: "You can get the sql during debugging." That's true, but if your code looks the way you're showing, I think it's likely that you're getting the SQL in the wrong way. Try extracting your IQueryable (everything prior to the ToList() call) into a separate variable. Then stop after that variable has been declared and check the `ToString()` on that IQueryable. It would also be good to double-check that `search` has the value you think it has.

Comment: To be sure you could always run a profiler on the DB :-)

Comment: Also, as a side note, you should make `.ToPagedList()` work off an IQueryable, and apply it before calling ToList(). Otherwise, you're loading all of the matching records into memory rather than just the handful that you want to display.

Comment: What database are you using (and if SQL Server - are you using a case sensitive collation)? What is the exact value of `search`?

Answer (score 3):

Another reason why to chop off the where is an optimization of the query:

if `search` is `string.Empty`

then

```
"your string".StartsWith(string.Empty)
```

always returns true.

---

On the other hand:

```
string s = null;
s.StartsWith(string.Empty);
```

will throw an error.

---

Just to ensure your `search` variable has the appropriate value, you could do the following to exclude the `string.Empty` case:

```
var newSearch = "hi".ToUpper();
db.SalesPersons.Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith(newSearch) ||
                           x.Address.StartsWith(newSearch) || 
                           x.Email.StartsWith(newSearch))
```

---

Not helping? You could try a profiler, to ensure that that's the actual SQL which goes to the Database, if it is: file a bug.

Answer (score 1):

One reason why the `WHERE` clause may be chopped off is EF provider not recognizing `ToUpper`, and deciding to run that part of the query in memory.

You can fix this by performing `ToUpper` outside the query, like this:

```
var upperSearch = search.ToUpper();
return View(db.SalesPersons.Where(x =>
    x.Name.StartsWith(upperSearch)
||  x.Address.StartsWith(upperSearch)
||  x.Email.StartsWith(upperSearch)
).ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 3));
```

Comment: I am not aware of EF deciding to "run in memory" implicit. If it cannot us to Upper, it should throw an exception IMO.

Comment: The accepted answer in that question points that EF can translate ToLower so imho it does not related with ToUpper or StartsWith. Question is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885885/how-to-write-ef-in-linq-to-include-comparison-by-lower-case

Comment: @Stefan I am reasonably certain that one of EFs (EF core?) got smart enough to do an implicit `AsEnumerable()` for things that it cannot translate to RDBMS. I am not sure what version it was, though, because by then I switched to Dapper :-)

Comment: @Stefan The query builder and query provider are responsible for deciding if/when/how to execute queries. For the standard EF providers they will *usually* make a best effort to turn things in to (for example) SQL, but will also fall back to in-memory enumeration of query results when it cannot determine how to run them in the query / on sql server.

Comment: Ah, dapper...nice....  btw, the ToUpper can be translated as @EmreSavcı question indicates.

Comment: @cwharris: okay, but, then why is the net full of `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method '' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. ` -like errors? They are due to the fact the method call cannot be translated. ... next to that, if EF(provider) does this kind of thing implicit, the load on the DB will be enormous.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight. Same problem exists.

Comment: @Stefan My comment was only to illustrate that each provider is different. I have seen first hand where EF would find a Select statement with a call to an instance method and turn it in to an in-memory enumeration (on an iqueryable). I agree that it *shouldn't* do that. I'm just saying that I have *seen* it happen. Could have very well been a bug that has since been fixed, as I don't run in to this any more.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it "smart" for EF to implicitly switch to an in-memory implementation. My esteem for the EF team would drop significantly if they decided that it was better to silently go and load every single value from the database when provided with an `IQueryable.Where`. I could *maybe* see them doing it for a `Select` statement. Can either of you, cwharris or dasblinkenlight, find a source (or provide a fiddle) indicating that this behavior is real?

Comment: Ah, okay, I understand now... thanks... that's one to remember when using an EF provider